# Can't figure out how to host web browser (e.g. IWebBrowser2) in Win32 dialog. ATL okay, no MFC

Tags: c++, winapi, activex, atl, iwebbrowser2

I'm attempting to host a web browser inside a dialog.  I am using C++ with Win32 and ATL, no MFC.  There is an ActiveX control (IWebBrowser2) that implements this functionality.  The trick is it appears as though I need to create a dialog class that implements dozens of COM member functions to accomplish this.  Is there no easier way?  I've been looking at ATL (not I cannot use MFC otherwise I would use CDHtmlDialog) but haven't found any answers.

Comment: Do you have any code to share?

Comment: Check this out - http://www.assembla.com/code/roatl-utilities/subversion/nodes/trunk/DispEventSample02/MainDlg.h. This is ATL+WTL too, and the code snippet is very compact. Basically you need `CAxDialogImpl` and sink interface.

Comment: I really like your code Roman!  Unfortunately I cannot bring in a dependency on WTL. :(

Comment: There is little from WTL in this code fragment, all the important classes are from WTL (`CAxDialogImpl`, `IDispEventImpl`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an excellent tutorial on how to accomplish exactly what I am trying to do.  Specifically it explains how to create a Dialog using ATL but not WTL or MFC that hosts a web browser (via IWebBrowser2).

http://www.arstdesign.com/articles/Win32_dialoghelpers.html

Answer (score 0):

Here's a CodeProject article that demonstrates the process: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/wtl/wtl4mfc6.aspx

It assumes you'll be using WTL but I think it could be used with only ATL. WTL is an extension of ATL.

Comment: I think at some point in past WTL started being usable without ATL (such as for example to be good for Express versions of Visual Studio too).

Comment: Thanks for the reply Mark.  Unfortunately I cannot bring in a dependency on WTL.  I'm looking at the code now trying to figure out how to accomplish this task with ATL only.